Symmetry of cartesian multicategories in first order logic syntax
Cartesian multicategories are symmetric multicategories with a weakening and contraction operations.
When thinking of multicategories as some kind of "algebra" (?) of terms of first order logic, I understand contraction as giving us the ability of using twice the same variable as in $f(x,x)$; I understand weakening as saying that the term $f(x)$ can be thought of as depending also on some other variable, say $y$, but that we are not using.
How should symmetry be interpreted in this same manner?
Why is $f(t,s) \equiv f(s,t)$ for terms $t$ and $s$?

Symmetry just means that you can swap variables, so $f(s, t)$ is a well-formed term in context $t, s$.

@NaïmFavier I don't follow, maybe there's something else I'm not understanding. Can you say a bit more? If I understand correctly symmetry in terms of diagrams says that we can move the strings around all we want, and that order doesn't matter. And the strings themselves say something about how to form the terms themselves, not the context, right?
For instance if I have a term $f(x,y)$ this will be a diagram with two straight lines, one for $x$ and one for $y$, and then they get jointed together by $f$.

Well, contraction doesn't say that $f(x, x) = f(x)$, it just says that $f(x, x)$ is well-formed in context $x$, so I don't know why you'd expect symmetry to say $f(t, s) = f(s, t)$. You'd express the latter equation as $f \circ \sigma = f$, where $\sigma$ itself is the symmetric braiding.

@NaïmFavier Ok, I get it. Thank you!
